# Plotting a large number of "lines" as shading or color intensity

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have various pandas dataframes with up to 2000 time series in it. Obviously, a simple `df.plot()` doesn't really show anything useful (and takes a few minutes to plot). But at least I can easily get (and plot) a (rolling) mean. Simple example:

```
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1000), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=1000))
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 14), index=ts.index, columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMN'))
mean_df = df.mean(1)
rolling_mean = mean_df.rolling(window = 60, center = True)
ax = df.plot(style=':')
rolling_mean.mean().plot(ax=ax)
```

[image]

With this small example, one can probably see how the underlying data "behaves":

It's pretty symmetric around zero and most of the data is between +1 and -1, quite a bit is between +1 and +2, as well as -1 and -2, with some stuff happening in the 2/3 bracket and some outliers going up (or down) to almost +(-)4.

Why can one easily grasp this? Obviously, it's due to the number of lines per area, and thus the intensity or shading of the area. Becomes even clearer when I go monochrome:

[image]

**However, this lacks a quantification for density or number of lines.
How can I turn this into something quantitative?**

I.e. the 2-4 bracket should have various shades of light grey,  1-2 medium greys, 0-1 dark greys, so that the mean would be placed on top of an almost black zone in the graph, so that I end up with 50 shades of grey and maybe a color bar to boot.

I could probably play around with various shades of grey as a base color and see what setting different alphas does for a better visual effect, but this seems hacky.

Another option would be to do something like `max_df = df.max(1)` and `min_df = df.min(1)` and then use matplotlib to fill between (`plt.fill_between(df.index, min_df, max_df)`) and rig some way to repeat this for various levels (i.e. 1, 2 and 3 standard deviations away from the mean) so that I would end with some kind of continuous box-plot.

**But I am wondering if there is a better way to do this.**

Also: I'm not really sure how to best describe what I want/need, so please, if you have any questions/comments about the question, please comment and I'll see what I can edit to make myself clearer.

Comment: Maybe rather a question for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). They also cover data visualization.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to visualize the data for density is with the Kernel Density Estimate:

```
df.plot.kde()
plt.xlim(-4,4)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is certainly an useful inbuilt feature, but sadly, not what I'm looking for, since I not only need the distribution of the data in total, but for every arbitrary point in time. So even if I'd go down to a monthly resolution, this approach would need 33 plots for the example and ~700 plots for my real data, leading me back to my starting point, namely, the plot being rather confusing.